# Keyword stuffing occuring unintentionally on e-commerce site

Tags: seo, keywords, ecommerce, keyword-stuffing

I am working on a category page of an e-commerce site. I want to rank this category page for a particular keyword. This category page has almost 30 products having the same keyword in the title with slight variation. As a result my keyword density goes to 5.2 (I am using yoast plugin in WordPress which gives me this data)
I thought I can do one of the things:

1) Create 2-3 more specific categories and create their separate category pages.
  So every category page will have 10 products. This will reduce the keyword density. However it is the same keyword and might cause keyword cannabalism.

2)Optimize the category page for the keyword I actually want to but use a similar keyword in the product titles. So this will remove the keyword density and also avoid keyword cannabalism.

I am just a beginner in SEO. I could be completely wrong. Please let me know if I am missing out anything . If there is an alternate solution, please let me know. Thanks in Advance

Comment: BTW- Keyword Density is a myth. Do natural work and do not worry about it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

If it would naturally appear (product list) then it's not keyword stuffing. That's a term relevant to an old technique used to make articles seem more on topic.

Google now takes a much more holistic view of content. Having a single page that has many links using the same keyword is fine if you've structured a category page and each page does indeed feature that word with a more appropriate frequency.